# Using tsql greater than sign in CASE Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

```
(case [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate())
   when (0) then (0) 
   when (1) then (4) 
   when (2) then (8)
    when (3) then (12)
     when (4) then (32) 
     when (5) then (40) 
     when (6) then (48) 
     when (7) then (56) 
     when (8) then (104) 
     when (9) then (117) 
     when (10) then (150) else (-1) end)
```

Now in my the last line, how can i say that 10 and above should be returned as 150?

Comment: What cases does your current `ELSE` clause account for?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: for when DateEngaged is NULL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't, the `CASE YourFunction WHEN ...` is for equalities only. If you need to use "greater than", you'll need to rewrite your expression this way:

```
CASE WHEN [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 0 THEN 0
WHEN [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 1 THEN 4
WHEN.....
WHEN [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) >= 10 THEN 150 ELSE -1 END
```

Answer (score 8):

You are using a `Simple Case statement` where logical expressions are not allowed. You need to use a `Searched CASE expression`. But in your case since you are using a function it will be bit costly to get the return value from the function for each expression.

[Here is MSDN Link for both Simple Case and Searched CASE Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx)

I would suggest you to use a `sub query with a Searched case` as bellow.

```
select case when results = 0 then 0
            when results = 1 then 4
            ...
            when results >= 10 then 150
            else -1 end as CaseResults
from (select [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) results
      from yourTable
     ) Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN MIN(value) <= 0 THEN 0 
     WHEN MAX(1/value) >= 100 THEN 1 
  END 
FROM Data
```

you can use any boolean expression in the WHEN clause

```
case 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 0) then (0) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 1) then (4) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 2) then (8)
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 3) then (12)
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 4) then (32) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 5) then (40) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 6) then (48) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 7) then (56) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 8) then (104) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) = 9) then (117) 
  when ([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) >= 10) then (150) 
  else (-1) end
```

you should save [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) in a variable before evaulation tho.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (from your comment) that when `DateEngaged` is `NULL`, it causes `YearsInService` to be `NULL`, then I'd remove your current `ELSE` clause, and then use that for `all other cases`, something like:

```
case COALESCE([dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()),-1)
when (-1) then (-1)
when (0) then (0) 
when (1) then (4) 
when (2) then (8)
when (3) then (12)
 when (4) then (32) 
 when (5) then (40) 
 when (6) then (48) 
 when (7) then (56) 
 when (8) then (104) 
 when (9) then (117) 
 else (150) end
```

If there's a concern about future-dated `DateEngaged` values, I'd deal with that inside of `YearsInService` rather than try to deal with it in the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

I like @kaf 's answer, just want add that you may reduce the number of case by this

```
select case when results BETWEEN 0 AND 3 then results * 4
            when results BETWEEN 4 AND 7 then results * 8
            when results BETWEEN 8 AND 9 then results * 13
            when results >= 10 then 150
            else -1 
        end as CaseResults
from (select [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) results
      from yourTable
     ) Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate())
   when (0) then (0) 
   when (1) then (4) 
   when (2) then (8)
    when (3) then (12)
     when (4) then (32) 
     when (5) then (40) 
     when (6) then (48) 
     when (7) then (56) 
     when (8) then (104) 
     when (9) then (117) 
     when IIF(case [dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate()) >= 10 
           ,[dbo].[YearsInService]([DateEngaged],getdate())
           ,10) 
        then (150) 
     else (-1) end
```

This equates all the cases above 10 to the value of the function.